# command + option + arrow keys (left or right) shortcut not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Suddenly the shortcut cmd + opt + arrow (left or right) stopped working. I used it to switch tabs in Chrome and move back and forth in code (IntelliJ).

I have tried resetting shortcuts and rebooting but this doesn't seem to work. It's just this one shortcut which is not working.

I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate, but I'm using 10.13.4.  Have you tried updating?  Also, did you check in System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts to see if they were overridden somehow?

Comment: @Allan No I did not update. No shortcut overridden. everything is on default

Comment: Try in Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting) to see if there's a conflict with something that get's loaded.  Also, try creating another user account to see if the problem persists there.

Comment: To switch tabs in Chrome (and almost any application that supports tabs in a single window), try the shortcut `Command` + `{` and `Command` + `}`.

Comment: Command + left arrow didn't work either.  Then I tried command + { and now the command + left arrow has been activated. Hope this helps others